The issue with the relationship between the CustomButton in the header and the dateClick and eventClick events
I am using FullCalendar version 4.4.3 in Salesforce.
Today, I added a custom button to the header, and afterward, I noticed that both eventClick and dateClick stopped working.
While the functions located in the header work, the dateClick and eventClick functionalities on the calendar do not.
The following message is displayed in the browser's developer console:
Uncaught (in promise) NotFoundError: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
initializeCalendar() {
    const calendarEl = this.template.querySelector('.calendar');
     if (!this.events || this.events.length === 0) {
            console.warn("No events to initialize the calendar with.");
            return; // 이벤트 데이터가 아직 로드되지 않은 경우
     }
   const categories = [...new Set(this.events.map(event => event.category))];
      this.categoryOptions = categories.map(cat => ({ label: cat, value: cat }));
      console.log('카테고리 옵션 ', this.categoryOptions);

    this.calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: ["dayGrid", "timeGrid", "list","interaction","moment"],
        defaultView: 'dayGridMonth',
        events :this.fetchEvents.bind(this),
        header : {
            right : 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,  customFilterButton',
            center : 'title',
            left : 'prev,next today'
        },
        views : {
            timeGridDay : {
                buttonText : '일',
                titleFormat : {year : 'numeric', month:'short'}
                },
            dayGridMonth : {
                buttonText : '월',
                slotDuration : '00:30:00',
                slotLabelFormat: {hour: '2-digit' ,minute:'2-digit',hour12:false}
                },
            timeGridWeek : {
                buttonText : '주',
                slotDuration : '00:15:00',
                slotLabelInterval : '01:00:00'
            }
        },
        dateClick : (info)=>{
             this.modalAction = 'create'; // 모달을 생성 모드로 설정
             this.isUpdate = false; // 새로운 이벤트 추가
             this.modalTitle = '일정 추가';
             this.isModalOpen = true; // 모달 열기
             this.isFirstModalOpen = true; // 첫 번째 모달 활성화
             this.isSecondModalOpen = false; // 두 번째 모달 비활성화
             this.selectedDate = info.dateStr; // 클릭한 날짜 설정
        },
        datesRender: () => {
            this.setupCustomDropdown();
        },
     eventClick: (info) => {
        this.modalAction = 'update'; // 모달을 수정 모드로 설정
            this.isUpdate = true; // 기존 이벤트 수정
            this.modalTitle = '일정 수정';
            this.isModalOpen = true; // 모달 열기
            this.isFirstModalOpen = false; // 첫 번째 모달 비활성화
            this.isSecondModalOpen = true; // 두 번째 모달 활성화

            // 이벤트 데이터 설정
            const convertSelectedEndDate = this.formatDateToISOString(info.event.end);
            const convertSelectedDate = this.formatDateToISOString(info.event.start);
            this.selectedEndDate = convertSelectedEndDate || convertSelectedDate; // 종료일
            this.selectedDate = convertSelectedDate; // 시작일
            this.selectedSubject = info.event.title; // 제목
            this.selectedCategory = info.event.extendedProps.category || ''; // 카테고리
     },
    customButtons : {
        customFilterButton : {
            text:'필터',
            click : ()=>{
                this.fetchApexFilterType();
            }
        }
    }

    });

